# Cross_val_score in cross validation - is it executed on training set or test set?

Tags: machine-learning

cross_val_score : what does it return ? The score for training / test set  ?! I have a model with 5 fold.what does the cross_val_score correspond to ?can someone explain in layman's terms?

Comment: Please add more tags. What library you are using? Be more precise in question.

Comment: 5 fold means dividing your train set into 5 subsets by randomly selecting examples and using 4 out of them for training and the rest one as development set for each epoch (Epoch: Complete pass on whole training set). In next epoch the data set will be divided randomly like this again. Note that, the development set is the data set on which we tune our model to work well and at that time learning happens. It is different from test set, as while testing neither any tuning to hyper parameter occurs nor any learning of the model occurs, only the performance to unknown data (test set) is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!  Cross-validation splits your training dataset into 5 parts (aka folds).  It then rotates which part of the dataset gets used for testing.

It's basically like this:

You have your training data.  You have no clue what machine learning algorithm to use, but you have a hunch that it might be either deep learning or linear regression.

So you take your training data and you divide it up into 5 different equal sections (randomize first tho).  You use 4 of those sections to train your deep learning model.  Then you test it by comparing the answers it gives you to the answers you know to be true, from the 5th section (the test/validation section).  You do this another 4 times, rotating which part gets to be the test part.  Then you take the average score of all 5 times, and that is your cross-validation score.

You repeat the process for linear regression.  Whichever algorithm gives you the best cross-validation score is the one you will pick, because it's the best for that problem.

Imagine you are picking between two cars: a Honda and a Toyota.  You don't want to just test-drive a car once before buying it.  It's a big decision.  So for the Honda, you test-drive it 5 times and you average your experience over those 5 times.  Same for the Toyota, you test-drive it 5 different times and average your experience so you can make an informed decision.

Cross-validation is basically taking a machine learning algorithm (or its hyperparameters, etc.) for a test-drive and seeing how it does.